# Encrypt internal drives and unlock with USB drive

Tags: server, encryption

I've setup a home server using Ubuntu 16.  I have a system boot drive (SSD) and 2 internal drives in a mirrored ZFS pool.  I'm running an AFP server (docker) for Time Machine backups, Nextcloud (snap) for dropbox/calendars/contacts/reminders, and Plex (docker) for media.

I'd like to encrypt my drives that are in the mirrored ZFS pool, but I need them to decrypt on boot (since this is a server with no monitor).  Decrypting on boot causes a problem, because if the server is stolen, the files are still readable, so I'd like the decryption key to be stored in a USB drive that will be screwed to some furniture, so that way if the server is stolen, the files on it aren't readable.

Are there any easy ways to accomplish this?  I'm not stuck on ZFS if there is a better filesystem to accomplish this.

Comment: I don't know much about ZFS, but LUKS encrypt with a deception key in the USB may work.